# "ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state" following updating eager loaded navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ninject, entity-framework-6, navigation-properties

I am using Entity Framework 6 and Ninject. I load a parent property via its repository, which uses eager loading to populate the sub-property, and attempt to update this sub-property by changing the Id. In other places in my code, EF correctly figures out that when this Id is updated, the associated navigation-property needs to be updated as well.

Eg.

```
public class Foo
{
   public int SubFooId { get; set; }

   //Navigation Properties:

   [JsonIgnore]
   public virtual Subfoo Subfoo { get; set; }
}

//Uses eager loading [ .Include("Subfoo") ] to populate Subfoo
var foo = container.Get<FooRepository>().FindByIdUseEagerLoad(1);

foo.SubFooId = 2;

container.Get<FooRepository>().Write(foo);
container.Get<MyContext>().CommitToDatabase();
```

However, here when committing this change, I receive the following error:

> The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship

If I instead update the property directly like so:

```
var newFoo = new Foo() { ... };
foo = newFoo;
```

...I do not receive an error, however the property is not actually changed in the database.

Any thoughts on why this may be occurring or the proper way to make this change?

Comment: It looks to me like you are changing the the Foreign Key (`Foo.SubfooId`) without updating the `Subfoo.Id` to the same value.
I'm pretty certain that you are not supposed to actually change the Foreign Key. Normally you should not even need to have the Foreign Key as an accessible property on the `Foo`. The reference is maintained by the `Foo.Subfoo` property by the ORM. At least i think so, i don't really know EF, just other ORMs.

Comment: If/when you have resolved the issue could you please give feedback on how you did so?

Comment: I tried all different combinations of updating the Foreign Key and/pr the accessible property itself and none worked. The only thing I could do to make it work was remove the eager loading from the FooRepository call.